# Understanding the total_timesteps parameter in stable-baselines' models

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I'm reading through the [original PPO paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf) and trying to match this up to the input parameters of the [stable-baselines PPO2](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo2.html) model.

One thing I do not understand is the `total_timesteps` parameter in the [`learn`](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo2.html#stable_baselines.ppo2.PPO2.learn) method.

The paper mentions

> One style of policy gradient implementation...  runs the policy for T timesteps (where T is much less than the
>   episode length)

While the stable-baselines documentation describes the `total_timesteps` parameter as

> (int) The total number of samples to train on

Therefore I would think that `T` in the paper and `total_timesteps` in the documentation are the same parameter.

What I do not understand is the following:

- Does `total_timesteps` always need to be less than or equal to the total number of available "frames" (samples) in an environment (say if I had a finite number of frames like 1,000,000). If so, why?
- By setting `total_timesteps` to a number less than the number of available frames, what portion of the training data does the agent see? For example, if `total_timesteps=1000`, does the agent only ever see the first 1000 frames?
- Is an episode defined as the total number of available frames, or is it defined as when the agent first "looses" / "dies"? If the latter, then how can you know in advance when the agent will die to be able set `total_timesteps` to a lesser value?

I'm still learning the terminology behind RL, so I hope I've been able to explain my question clearly above. Any help / tips would be very much welcomed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the stable-baselines source code

- total_timesteps is the number of steps **in total** the agent will do for any environment. The total_timesteps can be across several episodes, meaning that this value is not bound to some maximum.
- Let's say you have an environment with more than 1000 timesteps. If you call the learn function once, you would only experience the first 1000 frames, and the remaining part of the episode is unknown. In many experiments, you know how many timesteps the environment should last (i.e CartPole), but for environments with unknown length, this becomes less useful. BUT. If you call the learn function twice and say the environment episode had 1500 frames, you would see a full episode + 50 % of the 2nd.
- An episode is defined to the extent of when the terminal flag is set to true (In gym, this is often set after a max timestep as well) Many other RL implementations use total_episodes instead so that you do not have to care about time step consideration, but again, the downside would be that you could end up with only running 1 episode if you hit an absorbing state.

The total timestep argument also uses n_steps where the number of updates is calculated based as follows:

```
n_updates = total_timesteps // self.n_batch
```

where n_batch is n_steps times the number of vectorised environments.

This means that if you were to have 1 environment running with n_step set to 32 and total_timesteps = 25000, you would do 781 updates to your policy during the learn call (excluding epochs, as PPO can do several updates on a single batch)

The lesson is:

- For unknown sized envs, you would have to play with this value. Maybe create a running average episode length and use this value
- Where the episode length is known, set it to the desired number of episode you would like to train. However, it might be less because the agent might not (probably wont) reach max steps every time.
- TLDR play with the value (treat it as a hyperparameter)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This part `the agent might not (probably won't) reach max steps every time` is very troubling for me. Could you elaborate further on why this would happen?

Comment: @xicocaio In some environments you can have extenuating circumstances that cause the episode to end (produce 'done' signal) before reaching the maximum length, for example collision with self or with wall/floor.

Comment: May I ask if my data is 9000 rows ,what  total_timesteps should I set ?

Comment: e.g. could be 9000 to train one episode or 18000 to train two episodes