# StableBaselines3 / steps vs. total_timesteps vs. number of times environment is solved during training

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

`model.learn(total_timesteps=20)` takes much longer than I expected, so I'm trying to understand if I should:

1. Be frugal with time steps
2. Speed up my environment `env.step(action)`
3. Train even more time steps

---

Consider a simple environment:

- There are (x3) steps until `done=True`

I expected `model.learn(total_timesteps=20)` to take either:

1. 20 x 3 steps = 20 iterations (equiv. to 20 episodes)
2. 20 total steps (or perhaps 18 or 21 steps) = (x6) or (x7) episodes

---

This is a similar question and has no answer:  [Stackoverflow question A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72265349/stable-baselines3-package-model-learn-function-how-do-total-timesteps-and-n).

This answer ([Stackoverflow question B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700948/understanding-the-total-timesteps-parameter-in-stable-baselines-models)) implies that this is truly the total number of steps for all iterations of the `env`.  If this is the case, in my example above, it should run (x18) steps or (x6) times before halting.  However, it takes far longer than that to complete (I have timed it!).  **Why is this the case?**

- What is the right interpretation of `total_timesteps`?
- Where is the documentation that describes this in detail (not here... [link](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo.html))?

---

Example:  inspired by Nicholas Renotte's tutorial [Project 3 - Custom Environment](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqazRodnhxVXZGR1pGT1BJeld6akVWdEgzNlhTUXxBQ3Jtc0tsQk40c25lZzEtT2g1OTV6N09xbHU3MGRkR1czU2dwdFZ4TmdsVW1vSnpVNTNqV2UzSDlZdmI2bHJpYWJubFRwYVJESWhqVjJjLVhLQV9kM0JaeF8yNFIxcWxDd3pBcVpFRU5jcTVYb1hiTzJtY1hhZw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnicknochnack%2FReinforcementLearningCourse&v=Mut_u40Sqz4)

In the example below, note that:

1. Each environment can only execute precisely (x3) steps
2. The time required to run `episodes` is very, very small
3. The `total_timesteps` is the same as the number of loops of the `episodes`
4. The summary of `iterations` and `time_elapsed` seem unrelated to the `total_timesteps`

**Environment Class**

```
class ShowerEnv(Env):
    listTemperatureKnob = (10, 30, 50)
    shower_length = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = Discrete(3)
        self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([0], dtype=np.float32), high=np.array([100], dtype=np.float32))
        self.reset()
        
    def step(self, action):
        temperatureShowerHead = self.listTemperatureKnob[action]
        self.state = temperatureShowerHead
        self.shower_length -= 1 

        if self.state > 27 and self.state < 33: 
            reward =1 
        else: 
            reward = -1 
        
        if self.shower_length <= 0: 
            done = True
        else:
            done = False
        
        # Apply temperature noise
        #self.state += random.randint(-1,1)
        # Set placeholder for info
        info = {"temperatureShower":temperatureShowerHead}

        obs = np.array([self.state], dtype=np.float32)
        # Return step information
        return obs, reward, done, info

    def render(self):
        pass
    
    def reset(self):
        self.state = self.listTemperatureKnob[0]
        self.shower_length = 3
        obs = np.array([self.state], dtype=np.float32)

        return obs

env = ShowerEnv()
check_env(env, warn=True)
```

**Run (x5) Episodes**

```
timeStart = time.time()

episodes = 5
for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0 
    
    while not done:
        env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        n_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score+=reward
    print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
env.close()

timeEnd = time.time()
print("Elapsed Time: " + str(timeEnd- timeStart))
```

*Time Elapsed:  0.000999*

**Execute a `model` training**

```
log_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Logs')
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)

timeStart = time.time()
model.learn(total_timesteps=5)

timeEnd = time.time()
print("Elapsed Time: " + str(timeEnd- timeStart))
```

**Output**

```
Using cpu device
Wrapping the env with a `Monitor` wrapper
Wrapping the env in a DummyVecEnv.
Logging to Training\Logs\PPO_7
---------------------------------
| rollout/           |          |
|    ep_len_mean     | 3        |
|    ep_rew_mean     | -1.14    |
| time/              |          |
|    fps             | 1496     |
|    iterations      | 1        |
|    time_elapsed    | 1        |
|    total_timesteps | 2048     |
---------------------------------
```

*Time elapsed: 2.6916*

Comment: "much longer than I expected" - how many steps? And where is your code?

Comment: I think I addressed your questions with the update to this question...pls LMK if this addresses your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I shared the same confusion with you recently: the training process is quite longer than I expected when I set total_timesteps to even very small values like 1. But I just realised this is due to a parameter named n_steps required by PPO class in SB3.

n_steps represents the number of steps before a policy update, and will be set by default to 2048. This is why the training process would always go through 2048 steps when I gave a value smaller than 2048 to total_steps. After I manually set n_steps to a smaller value, the problem has been solved.

So for your case, if you

> expect `model.learn(total_timesteps=20)` to take either:
>
> 1. 20 x 3 steps = 20 iterations (equiv. to 20 episodes)
> 2. 20 total steps (or perhaps 18 or 21 steps) = (x6) or (x7) episodes

you could respectively try either:

1. `model = PPO(policy, env, n_steps=3).learn(total_timesteps=60)`
2. `model = PPO(policy, env, n_steps=3).learn(total_timesteps=20)`

For more information on n_steps, you could refer to the parameter part in the [PPO documentation](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo.html#parameters) here, but notice n_steps * n_envs must be greater than 1, which means if you only have one environment in your case, the value of n_steps must be greater than 1.

Hope this helps!